# How to define a type constraint for any channel type

Tags: go, generics, channel

I'm trying to define a funcion that returns the percentage of usage of a given channel:

```
func ChannelUsagePct[T any](channel chan T) int {
    channelCap := cap(channel)
    channelLen := len(channel)
    if channelCap == 0 {
        // Unbuffered channel
        return 0
    }
    return 100 * channelLen / channelCap
}

func main() {
    twoWayChannel := make(chan int, 10)
    var sendOnlyChannel chan<- int = twoWayChannel
    var recvOnlyChannel <-chan int = twoWayChannel

    fmt.Println(ChannelUsagePct(twoWayChannel))
    fmt.Println(ChannelUsagePct(sendOnlyChannel)) // Does not work 
    fmt.Println(ChannelUsagePct(recvOnlyChannel))  // Does not work 
}
```

Now the thing is that this works for the first channel but not for the second and third, without changing the func's signature. But if I change the signature, I need to either choose the channel to be receive only, or send only. Is there a way to define a channel that is zero-way? E.g. cannot be read nor written to, I just want to use `cap` and `len` funcs on it.
Ideally the `ChannelUsagePct` should work for any of the 3 cases.

Comment: There is no "zero-way" channel. Why do you think you need to create channels which are send or receive only? A one-way-only channel can't be used for any normal channel operations, so there is no real reason to make one. If you are only going to read `len` and `cap`, those values can be passed as `int`

Comment: @JimB The idea of this function is to be generic and reused by different parts of my applications, that may have channels that were defined as send ore receive only (because their interfaces define it that way, to be safe). The thing is that I cannot make one function that generically works for all the types of channels.

Comment: OK, I see what you're asking. The channel structural typing makes a type constraint for all 3 forms of a channel not very useful because it's going to require instantiation of the element type in the signature. I think in this case you would have to use reflection, or type switch over all the possibilities.

Comment: You can kind of do it this way, but that element type can't be inferred: https://go.dev/play/p/Oj1iUdKYDmU. Maybe that's sufficient for your use case?

Comment: @JimB that is great! Yeah, that basically would work. Feel free to post an answer with that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to allow all three possible forms of a channel, a separate type constraint needs to be defined.

```
type Chan[T any] interface {
    chan T | <-chan T | chan<- T
}
```

This will require instantiating the type constraint with the type of `T` when it's used, which can be done with another type parameter:

```
func Cap[T any, C Chan[T]](c C) int {
    return cap(c)
}
```

Because of that instantiation the entire type cannot be inferred, but only the channel element type needs to be supplied:

```
ch := make(chan int, 3)
i := Cap[int](ch)
fmt.Println(i)
// 3
```

https://go.dev/play/p/1lx5R4MFvFx